# [edk2-platforms]Vlv2TbltDevicePkg built failed for 'error: symbol `InternalX86DisablePaging64.0' undefined'

Tags: uefi

I compiled Vlv2TbltDevicePkg and operated according to the following URL:

```
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-platforms/tree/master/Platform/Intel/Vlv2TbltDevicePkg
```

The compiled command is as follows:

```
build -a IA32 -a X64 -n 5 -t VS2019 -b DEBUG -p Vlv2TbltDevicePkg\PlatformPkgX64.dsc
```

The result is the following error message:
edk2p\Build\Vlv2TbltDevicePkgX64\DEBUG_VS2010x86\X64\MdePkg\Library\BaseLib\BaseLib\OUTPUT\X64\DisablePaging64.iii:35: error: symbol `InternalX86DisablePaging64.0' undefined

```
   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'c:\nasm\nasm.EXE' : return code '0x1'
```

My version of Nasm is nasm-2.13.03, how can I solve the error about nasm?
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I am also getting this error, any pointers please!

Answer (score 0):

I update nams to v2.15.05. It works fine!

Comment: Correct:  NASM 2.15.05.